# Access class in different file

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm still a newbie to swift and I can't get a clear answer on a couple things.

So far I've just been using a single file in playgrounds. 
If I want to use more files, how can I access data (variables and functions) from classes created there in my main file that controls the view?

From what I understand having multiple files would just be for convenience so I don't have could to write it again.

(Also on the side) what does it mean when a function has private, public or just 'func'?

I'm using swift 3 playgrounds

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making things `public` will make them importable from other modules. Making it `private` will make it only accessible by methods within its containing scope (encapsulation). For code that lives at the top level, this scope is the entire `.swift` file it lives in. Without either access modifier (just bare “`func`”), your thing will default to `internal`, which means it is accessible from any other code within the same module, but not by code in a different module.

A special case is the `fileprivate` modifier which restricts access to the `.swift` file the code lives in. For code that does not live in a class or struct, this does the exact same thing as `private`. Some Swift designers discourage use of this modifier, and it may be removed in future versions of Swift.

There is a fifth access modifier in Swift, `open`, which does the exact same thing as `public`, except it also allows subclassing, and only applies to classes. This one is rarely used, but useful for certain library interfaces.

To import all the `public` symbols in a module, use

```
import Module
```

To import a [single](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID354) `public` symbol, use

```
import var Module.variable
import func Module.function
import struct Module.structure
import class Module.class
...
```

Comment: I created a file in the playground named tester and in it made a class named example. I can't "import tester" nor "import example" in my main file

Comment: are `tester` and `example` the names of your modules?

Comment: "Example" is the name of the module (which is the name of the new file created as I understand). "Tester" is the name of a class created in this module (which contains a variable)

Comment: For a project with a single target, you shouldn't need to use the *import* statement. It's when you add a Framework target that you need this.

Comment: @dfd so how can I access variables from that file in my main file

Comment: Pretty much the same way as classes - you can make the *public*. If you declare a var/let/func as public, you *should* have access. If you declare a var/let/func as public within a class, you now have *instance* variables and need to instantiate the class they are part of. *This isn't specific to Swift, this is really OOP101 - OOP == Object-Oriented Programming. The only thing that **may** be specific to Swift is the syntax. I'd recommend studying up on this, particularly "variable scope".*

Comment: I think I found out my it's not working. I'm using playgrounds on iPad and when I created tried to new file it actually created a new "Page". Would you know how to create a new .swift file in the same .xcplaygrounds on iPad?